# Nested "for" loops in Python-Same loop but not working-Turtles

Tags: python, loops, nested, turtle-graphics

I have only been learning Python for 1 week. Here's my code:

```
def board():
    colorA=input("Please choose a first color for the CheckerBoard: ")
    colorB=input("Please choose a second color for the CheckerBoard: ")
    size=int(input("Please choose a box size: "))
    num=int(input("Please choose a side length for the board: "))
    x=-250
    y=250
    c=colorA
    x=-250
    for num in range(num):
        y=y-size
        for num in range(num):
            Fbox(x,y,size,c)
            x=x+size
            if(c==colorA):
                c=colorB
            elif(c!=colorA):
                c=colorA
```

It just pretty much ignores the first "for" loop.

Comment: For sanity, do not re-use the same variable for different purposes.

Comment: Sorry....I just started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem is reusing `num` as the loop variable - use a *different* variable. This reuse of the same variable makes the first inner loop run effectively `for num in range(0)` and the second `for num in range(1)`, etc. (As `num` is re-assigned by the outer loop each iteration.)

Instead the code should have the loops like `for x in range(num) .. for y in range(num)`. Where `x` and `y` are introduced as a the loop variables and *not* outside the loop as currently done.

The position can then be calculated using `x*size+offset_x`; this also eliminates the need to manually do the increments on x/y. Going with the above step logic, that would be

```
x_pos = x * size - 250
y_pos = (-1 * y) * size + 250
Fbox(x_pos, y_pos, size, c)
```